# itext PushbuttonField behavior

Tags: button, itext, behavior

I'm creating pdfs with iText and have created "invisible" (i.e. no color, no icon) buttons (PushbuttonField) at the left and right of a pdf. When clicked, the document advances to the next or previous page.

The default behavior of buttons (at least in Acrobat) is for the color to be inverted when clicked. I would like to turn off this feedback.

Acrobat has a "Behavior" property (in addition to Layout, which is accessible in iText) for buttons that defaults to "invert". I would like the behavior to be set to "None" instead but cannot figure out how to define the button in iText.

Here is the (functioning - save the unwanted visual feedback) code I am using:

```
    PushbuttonField prevButton = new PushbuttonField(writer, new Rectangle(0, 0, 72, pageHeight), "Prev Page" + buttonNo++);
    field = prevButton.getField();
    field.setAction(new PdfAction(PdfAction.PREVPAGE));
    writer.addAnnotation(field);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without testing, I'd say you'd need:

```
field.setHighlighting(PdfFormField.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
```

Can you test this and confirm if I'm right?

As an alternative you could use:

```
field.setWidget(new Rectangle(0, 0, 72, pageHeight), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
```

Comment: Confirmed. I've also found a different solution using PdfAnnotation without a button:
        PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(writer, pos, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE, action);
        link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));
        writer.addAnnotation(link);